# What's the meaning of 'Igel fressen'?

Tags: expression

In a drama "Extra" episode 8, there is a statement.

> Sag ihr, ich habe einen Igel gefressen oder dass ich zum Mond gefahren bin.

This is what Nick tells his friend to make a woman (Edeltraut) leave. She is asking for Nick outside the door.
Does 'to eat hedgehog' have any special meaning?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. (you can make it an answer, so that I can select.)

Comment: Suicide by hedgehog ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context: "Extra ep 8"? Is that a TV series or sth? One that is dubbed or originally German language?

Comment: @Janka   Ich erinnere mich allerdings an eine Geschichte aus dem Kanon deutscher Schulbuchliteratur erinnern, bei der es hauptsächlich darum ging, dass sich Leute einen Igel braten (in Lehm verpackt auf dem Feuer). Komme jetzt nicht auf den Autor... einer der Klassiker aus den 50ern bis 60ern...

Comment: @LangLangC it's a situation comedy made in 5 languages. You can find it in German version on Youtube by searching "Extra in German". It's all 13 episodes and has German subscript.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Dann würde man aber doch sagen "Igel gegessen", nicht "gefressen". Übrigens: "Die Igel!" (Es geschah am hellichten Tag) - passt auch nicht, aus gleichem Grund. Ich nenne das Rumkugeln.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It has no special meaning.

This just means:

> Tell her, that I have done something, that she never will believe.

or:

> Lie to her, and do it in a way that she knows for sure that you are lying.

Nick doesn't care what Edeltraut thinks about him. He just wants her to leave .